# 405 Method Post Not Allowed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wrote the following code:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsCreation|permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def change_password(self, request):
        print(request.user)
```

With the corresponding route in `urls.py`:

```
path('api/users/password', views.UserViewSet.as_view({'post': 'change_password'}))
```

But when I make a request to `'api/users/password/'`, I get this error:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The [**`ReadOnlyModelViewSet`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#readonlymodelviewset) only support the ***HTTP GET*** method, as the name indicates.

In order to support other methods, you need to use [**`ModelViewSet`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) class (or other suitable classes)

For example:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): # change the super class
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsCreation | permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

**Side Note:** the method `change_password(...)` does seem like a ***custom action***, but you are missing [**`@action`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) decorator.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadOnlyModelViewSet` only provides the 'read-only' actions and that's why you are getting error `POST not allowed`. You can read more about it [Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#readonlymodelviewset)